# Build Singularity container using GitLab CI

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, virtualization, singularity-container

I want to build a singularity image in GitLab CI. Unfortunately, the [official containers](https://quay.io/repository/singularity/singularity) fail with:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.5.0 (ece86343) on gitlab-ci d6913e69
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image quay.io/singularity/singularity:v3.7.0 ...
Pulling docker image quay.io/singularity/singularity:v3.7.0 ...
Using docker image sha256:46d3827bfb2f5088e2960dd7103986adf90f2e5b4cbea9eeb0b0eacfe10e3420 for quay.io/singularity/singularity:v3.7.0 with digest quay.io/singularity/singularity@sha256:def886335e36f47854c121be0ce0c70b2ff06d9381fe8b3d1894fee689615624 ...
Preparing environment
Running on runner-d6913e69-project-2906-concurrent-0 via <gitlab.url>...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in <repo-path>
Checking out 708cc829 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Error: unknown command "sh" for "singularity"
```

immediately at the beginning, when using a job like this:

```
build-singularity:
  image: quay.io/singularity/singularity:v3.7.0
  stage: singularity
  script:
    - build reproduction/pipeline/semrepro-singularity/semrepro-singularity.sif reproduction/pipeline/semrepro-singularity/semrepro-singularity.def
  only:
    changes:
      - reproduction/pipeline/semrepro-singularity/semrepro-singularity.def
      - reproduction/pipeline/semrepro-singularity/assets/mirrorlist
      - .gitlab/ci/build-semrepo-singularity.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - reproduction/pipeline/semrepro-singularity/semrepro-singularity.sif
    expire_in: 1 hour
  interruptible: true
```

For me, it seems like GitLab is trying to use a shell that doesn't exist? How are they supposed to work? In the [official example](https://gitlab.com/singularityhub/gitlab-ci/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) they're using a special version of the docker image called `-gitlab`, but that unfortunately isn't available anymore. Any ideas? I can't imagine it isn't possible to build singularity containers within CI? Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:** According to @tsnowlan's answer, overriding the entrypoint fixes the above issue. However, now the build fails with:

```
singularity build semrepro-singularity.sif semrepro-singularity.def
INFO:    Starting build...
INFO:    Downloading library image
84.1MiB / 84.1MiB [========================================] 100 % 28.7 MiB/s 0s
ERROR:   unpackSIF failed: root filesystem extraction failed: extract command failed: ERROR  : Failed to create user namespace: not allowed to create user namespace: exit status 1
FATAL:   While performing build: packer failed to pack: root filesystem extraction failed: extract command failed: ERROR  : Failed to create user namespace: not allowed to create user namespace: exit status 1
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to finagle it a bit to make it play nice with gitlab CI. The easiest way I found was to clobber the docker entrypoint and have script step be the full singularity build command. We're using this to build our singularity images with v3.6.4, but it should work with v3.7.0 as well.

*e.g.,*

```yaml
build-singularity:
  image: 
    name: quay.io/singularity/singularity:v3.7.0
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: singularity
  script:
    - singularity build reproduction/pipeline/semrepro-singularity/semrepro-singularity.sif reproduction/pipeline/semrepro-singularity/semrepro-singularity.def
  ...
```

*edit:* the gitlab-runner used must also have `privileged` enabled. This is the default on the [gitlab.com shared runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/13.6/ee/user/gitlab_com/index.html#linux-shared-runners), but if using your own runners you'll need to make sure that is set in their config.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, this fixes the initial issue that building won't even start! However, it runs into another problem which I experienced before when trying a selfmade docker image. I thought this might be an issue with my custom docker issue, but appareantly it is not. Build fails with `ERROR:   unpackSIF failed: root filesystem extraction failed: extract command failed: ERROR  : Failed to create user namespace: not allowed to create user namespace`. Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot the sudo. Use that and it should work

Comment: Wait no, it should be running as root. That's odd

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I tried it using `sudo`, but unfortunately, that doesn't fix the issue. I already read somewhere that this might require running the Docker container with `--privileged`, which of course is not available on a GitLab platform. Any ideas what might be different in your case?

Comment: Aha, yes I think that's it. We run our own gitlab-runners that are run with `--privileged`. Though it looks like the shared runners should be too: https://docs.gitlab.com/13.6/ee/user/gitlab_com/index.html#linux-shared-runners

Comment: Yeah, I think that means that in our GitLab instance they are not. I'll ask the admins about this. Any ideas for a possible workaround?

Comment: Ah, if you're running on a managed instance you're gonna be out of luck until they enable privileged mode on the runner. It's a hard require for docker-in-docker or singularity-in-docker

Comment: Okay, that's unfortunate. Thanks a lot for your effort!